# ¿Como puedo pasar variables en stylus del archivo principal al importado?

Tags: css, nodejs, stylus

Estoy haciendo un *grid system* con stylus. Tengo varios archivos `.styl` con diferentes mixins y funciones pero para simplificar pongamos que solo es uno llamado `grid.styl`. Un usuario que quiera usarlo solo tendría que crear su propio archivo de stylus, importar el archivo `grid.styl` y empezar a escribir su css.

Tengo unas variable en ese archivo que quiero que el usuario pueda modificar. Las variables tienen un valor por defecto pero pueden ser sobrescritas por el usuario. La única manera que he encontrado para poder usar los valores del usuario es importar su archivo `.styl` (en realidad tengo que usar `@require` para que no entre en un bucle pero eso es lo de menos).

El problema es que no sé cómo se llamará su archivo así que tengo que importar la carpeta donde esté, lo que me crea dos problemas, el primero que si el usuario tiene varios archivos de stylus los importará todos y el segundo que le obligo a poner los archivos en una carpeta y con una jerarquía concretas.

¿Habría alguna otra manera de recoger esos valores del usuario?

**Ejemplo de código:**

*archivo stylus del usuario*

```
@require 'grid'

ratio = 1.618
base-line-height = 1
base-font-size ?= 14px

.container
  container(800px)
  background-color rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.45)
  padding 20px;

div
    col(1/2, 5%)
    border:solid 1px red

...
```

*archivo grid.styl*

```
@require '../*'

// estas son las variables que quiero que el usuario pueda modificar
ratio ?= 1.5
base-line-height ?= 1.5
base-font-size ?= 16px
```

Comment: Me parece que tu mejor opción aquí es usar un fichero separado para tus variables y que los usuarios sobreescriban los valores que pones en él. De otra forma siempre te vas a arriesgar a que te haga un bucle.

Comment: No sabía que pretendías usar `npm` como tu modo de distribución. Yo sólo estoy siguendo la lógica de frameworks bien establecidos y populares como [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) los cuales te dan un precompilado y un source que puedes modificar con SASS y LESS que son preprocesadores igual que stylus. Si vas al [getting started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) y descargas los diferentes enlaces verás que todos tienen un fichero llamado `variables.algo` que es donde haces las modificaciones para que tus estilos tengan las modificaciones deseadas.

Comment: Básicamente lo que puedes hacer es incluir una copia de ese fichero `variables` en tu documentación y especificas que debe ser incluida de esta forma `variables.styl` > `grid.styl` > `user.styl`. Esto no es un problema que afecte a `stylus` solamente sino a todos los lenguajes preprocesadores.

Comment: El plugin que mencionas es para hacer las *media queries* más simples. No es lo mismo que lo que pones en tu pregunta ya que tu quieres lidiar con la *inclusión de variables* y *estilos por defecto*. Las media queries solo se aplican ante determinadas condiciones mientras que con las variables se puede llegar a afectar todos los estilos de tu código incluyendo las media queries.

Comment: Si pero entonces el usuario tendría que "adivinar" cual es el nombre de esa variable o la puedes poner en la documentación como lo hace [el plugin](https://github.com/jescalan/rupture#variables) y como te recomendé anteriormente. El proceso de compilación te genera el CSS usando el mixin con el valor que tiene la variable en ese momento. Si el usuario no lo ha establecido primero no funcionará. Sólo sigue el ejemplo del plugin y documenta tus variables y no tendrás problemas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40789/discussion-between-devconcept-and-blonfu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema era que tengo que importar el archivo después de modificar las variables, de esta forma las variables del usuario prevalecen sobre las del archivo *grid.styl*:

*Archivo stylus del usuario:*

```
ratio = 1.618
base-line-height = 1
base-font-size ?= 14px

@import'grid'

.container
  container(800px)
  background-color rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.45)
  padding 20px;

div
    col(1/2, 5%)
    border:solid 1px red

...
```

Con esto además no necesito importar los estilos desde *grid.styl* y me evito el problema de obligar al usuario a poner sus estilos en un lugar concreto, además puedo usar `@import` en lugar de `@require` porque ya no hay peligro de entrar en bucle.